# Is there an equivalent of C's #define in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, constants

Title says it all. I'm sure there's already answers on the internet, but due to Google's limitations in searching for non alphanumeric characters, I'm only getting results about TypeScript `define` keyword.

Comment: No, there isn’t. This sounds like an XY problem, what is the end result you’re after?

Comment: Nothing, just curious.